# Ruby on Rails create method not saving parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My create method is not working and it used to work. Thanks in advance!

```
<%= form_for :category, url: categories_path do |f| %>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :title %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :title %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <%= f.submit %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

my controller:

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @category = Category.where(id: params[:id]).first
  end

  def create
    @category = Category.create(title: params[:category][:title])
    redirect_to @category
  end
end
```

Note: params[:category][:title] is in fact the correct value

my model:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events

  attr_accessor :title
end
```

my migration:

```
class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :categories do |t|
      t.string :title

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

And when I go to my form and input "main" (or anything else) in the text box and then click save It is saved in my database as:

```
 id | title |      created_a      |     updated_at      |
---------------------------------------------------------
 1  | NULL  | 2013-11-16 21:30:59 | 2013-11-16 21:30:59 |
```

As you can see I am not being able to save my parameter in the database. This was not happening to me before, I went and tried to make some changes to my structure and this issue started happening so I reverted and now it does not even work even though I reverted. By the way I am using a mysql database. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you just upgrade to Rails 4?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While Rails 4 does *favor* strong parameters, it requires a developer action to enable them.  First, the developer has to include a module in the model to turn them on:

```
include ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection
```

Without that include using the require/permit pair that many here have mentioned has no negative effect.  (The converse is not true -- if you include the module but do not sanitize the params using require/permit then you'll get an error).

Mateo's problem is *much* simpler.  In the Category class definition you have included

```
attr_accessor :title
```

That's good form for Ruby... but not with Rails.  The attr_accessor macro creates a getter/setter pair for an attribute named 'title' on the class.  Unfortunately, that means that the inherited code from ActiveRecord will *not* create the magic methods that shuttle the title attribute to/from the database.  Remove the attr_accessor for title and you'll be in business.

```
class Category
  has_many :events
end
```

Answer (score 1):

As @CDub said in his answer, in Rails 4, you have to use strong parameters so an example would be

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @category = Category.where(id: params[:id]).first
  end

  def create
    @category = Category.create(params.require(:category).permit(:title))
    redirect_to @category
  end
end
```

And in your model you could remove `attr_accessible`

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use a separate method to permit params.

```
private
  def category_params
    params.require(:category).permit(:title)
  end
```

And then in the create method:

```
@category = Category.create(category_params)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you upgraded to Rails 4, Rails 4 now favors strong parameters in place of `attr_accessible` and `attr_protected`.  It's likely that your parameters are being blacklisted because of Rails 4 defaulting to use strong parameters.

Check out [this gem](https://github.com/rails/protected_attributes) with details on upgrading from Rails 3 to Rails 4, and [the documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html) for differences between Rails 3 and Rails 4.

Comment: While true, the models would have to include the ForbiddenAttributesProtection module for strong params to have an effect.  See below.